# Can't open file in cp program

Tags: c, cp

I'm working on a custom version of cp where the arguments are two directories and the files from the first directory are copied to the second. My current problem is getting the files in the first directory to open. When I get to the "open files" part of the code I get an error saying that there is no file, which doesn't make sense because the file name is printing out in the error. Am I missing something simple? I think I included enough of the code.

```
int main(int ac, char *av[]) {    

int     in_fd, out_fd, n_chars;
char    buf[BUFFERSIZE];
struct stat sb;
DIR *copyFrom;
DIR *copyTo;
struct dirent *ep;

/* open dirs */
copyFrom = opendir(av[1]);
copyTo = opendir(av[2]);

while(ep = readdir(copyFrom))
{
    /* open files */
    if ( (in_fd=open(ep->d_name, O_RDONLY)) == -1 )
        oops("Cannot open", ep->d_name);

    if ( (out_fd=creat(ep->d_name, COPYMODE)) == -1 )
        oops( "Cannot create", ep->d_name);

    /* copy files */
    while ( (n_chars = read(in_fd , buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0 )
        if ( write( out_fd, buf, n_chars ) != n_chars )
            oops("Write error to ", av[2]);

    if ( n_chars == -1 )
        oops("Read error from ", av[1]);

    /* close files */
    if ( close(in_fd) == -1 || close(out_fd) == -1 )
        oops("Error closing files","");
}
}
```

Comment: where does av[] get defined?

Comment: It's in main. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1):

The `DIR` record returned from `readdir` only returns the basename of the file. You need to concatenate this with the directory to correctly open the files.

Something like this:

```
char srcfile[1024];
sprintf("%s/%s", av[1], ep->d_name);
if ( (in_fd=open(srcfile, O_RDONLY)) == -1 )
        oops("Cannot open", srcfile);
```

Comment: Or change the working directory, also the OP must check if `opendir()` returned `NULL`.

Comment: Both statements are true -- I was just trying to point him in the right direction.

Comment: Make sure `av[1]` is not `NULL`. Also make sure you check the return value of `opendir()`